# How to show all subcategories of a particular category in alphabetical order with Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I want to show all subcategories of a particular category in an alphabetical order just like I added in admin.
I am showing my all subcategories in this page `app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/catalog/product/product-listing.phtml`

The code is

```
<?php
$categories = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getChildren();
$catArray = explode(',', $categories);
?>
<div class="categories_list">
<?php
foreach($catArray as $child){

$parentCategoryId = $child; 
$categoriesgot = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId)->getChildren();
$catArraygot = explode(',', $categoriesgot);
$categoriesCount = count($catArraygot);

//echo $categoriesCount;

    $_child = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/category' )->load($child );
    $products_count = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($child)->getProductCount();
//############################################################################################################

//$parentCategoryId = $child;   
//$categoriesgot = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId)->getChildren();
$category_name = Mage::registry('current_category')->getName(); 


if($categoriesCount >= 1 AND $products_count < 1)
{
    $value = $categoriesCount." Categories";
}
else if($categoriesCount == 1 AND $products_count > 0)
{
    $value = $products_count." Products";
}
else if ($categoriesCount >= 1 AND $products_count > 1)
{
    $value = $categoriesCount." Categories";

}if($categoriesCount == 1 AND $products_count == 0)
{
    $value = $products_count." Products";
}

//echo $products_count;
    ?>


      <div class="listing">
      <a href="<?php echo $_child->getUrl() ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $_child->getImageUrl();?>" alt="<?php echo $_child->getName()?>"  width="135" height="135"/>

               <h3 class="product-name"><?php echo $_child->getName() ?></h3></a>
                        <?php if($category_name != "Brands"){?>     <p><?php echo $value;?></p><?php }?>
  </div>
<?php 
}
?>
</div>
```

I don't know in which order subcategories are showing  because sub-categories are all mixed up.
If anyone knows this,please help me out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get the list of subcategories in an alphabetical order or in the order entered in the backend, provided you have the parent category.

```
$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
     ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $category->getId()) //get only direct children of main category
     ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1) //in case you want only the active categories
     ->addAttributeToSort('name') //sort by name
     //->addAttributeToSort('position') //in case you want to sort by position
;

foreach ($children as $child) {
    //do something with $child
}
```

This way you avoid calling `load` in a loop that can cause performance issues.

Comment: Please i post my code above.you just tell me where i will add this code

Comment: please use your code in my above code and post the updated code

Comment: @PrinceKumar. Your code is kind of long and it's missing the indentation. I don't know exactly where it goes. Probably at the top. Try to see where it fits, or make your code look nicer so I can easily read it.

Comment: it shows error  Call to a member function getId() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work for you

```
<?php
$cats =Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(10);
$catIds = explode(',',$cats);

$categories = array();
foreach($catIds as $catId) {
       $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId); 
       $categories[$category->getName()] = $category->getUrl();
}

ksort($categories, SORT_STRING);
?>

<ul>
<?php foreach($categories as $name => $url): ?>
    <li>
    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: please use this code in my above code and please post the updated code here.

Comment: just replace (10) in getCategories(10) with the id of your category id